# How can I identify the following group of three generators

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Let us consider the group $G= \langle a,b,c \mid aba=bab, aca=cac \rangle$.
How can I determine the group identical with this group?

Comment: What sort of identification are you hoping for?

Comment: Identification with  known finite group

Comment: The group is not finite, so you will not succeed.

Comment: What Derek said (it is easy to see this be considering for example the abelianization).

Comment: In general a group with less (or fewer if you prefer) relations than generators is always infinite.

Comment: @Derek Holt, thank for your response. Sorry for my mistake. The group is infinite. Is this group abelian or not. How can I determine?

Comment: If it was abelian, it would be cyclic. Is it cyclic?

Comment: The homorphism $G \to S_3$ with $a \mapsto (1,2)$ and $b,c \mapsto (2,3)$ proves that it is not abelian.